# Registration in Firebase using OTP

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make an app in Android Studio where the user will have to register in Firebase using his mobile phone number. But the user would only be allowed to register if he verifies his phone number with the OTP sent to him via SMS.

I don't want to allow anyone with a fake phone number to register and hence I need them to verify. So is there a way to do so in Firebase?

I tried the `auth.signInWithCredential()` method but it seems to allow users to only sign in with an `OTP`. I also don't want my users to type an `OTP` every time they sign in. I want them to sign in using only their password and phone number.

Comment: Check it out. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-phone-authentication-android-tutorial/

Comment: @Ricky please look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth